# Preemption control in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, openmp

Imagine the following

```
    #omp parallel num_threads=16
    {
     Code
     #omp barrier
     Code
     #omp barrier

     }
```

I want that `thread=0` runs to barrier and then the CPU Core switches to `thread=1`. I want that the omp code (better, the scheduler of the Operating System) switches between threads only when  the present code (present thread) reaches a barrier. I want the latency of switching between threads to be a minimum. My CPU could have several cores.

Can that be done?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want a thread to run each section of your code. If you want to do that in parallel, that is, all sections at the same time, but one thread per section, simply use the `sections` directive. If you want it to be sequential, one section after the other, why use OpenMP in the first place? Just write your code normally. If you *really want* to use OpenMP for that, maybe use N critical `sections`? Check out [Stackoverflow em portugues](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Hello, welcome on StackOverflow. You do not have to sign below your post. Your name is displayed under each of your questions and comments automatically.

Comment: You're asking a language-level solution for an OS-level problem. Neither C++ nor OpenMP take threads preemption into consideration, because it's a concept of a lower level. You can hack thread priority, but that could become ugly. In general, the best thing to do is have one thread per core, and that will minimize context switches.

Comment: Eran, Thinking better, when the number of processes is not multiple of the number of cores there will be remaining cores in the last launch of processes and the advantage obtained in context switching is lost.